# Form not binding in Django

Tags: django, forms, post, view

In one of my Django views where I am posting data, the form is invalid due to it being unbound, although the form is definitely bound with data. I am not entirely sure why this is happening. The application I am working on uses Angular for the front end, so I am not using Django's form class in my HTML, but it shouldn't matter right because Django's form class just creates HTML widgets ?

[image: Login Form]

login.html

```
<div class="account-login" id="login-view">
  <div class="card card-half">
    <h2 class="text-center">Welcome back!</h2>
    <h4 class="text-center">Sign in to your account.</h4>

    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="vm.errorMessage">
      {{ vm.errorMessage }}
    </div>

    <form class="form-horizontal" name="form" ng-submit="vm.login(vm.auth)">
        {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>

        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7">
          <input type="email" id="email"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="name@example.com"
              ng-model="vm.auth.email"
              required
              hl-focus>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>

        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7">
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="******"
              ng-model="vm.auth.password"
              required minlength="6">

          <div class="has-warning" ng-if="form.password.$dirty">
            <div class="help-block" ng-messages="form.password.$error">
              <div ng-message="minlength">Please enter at least six characters.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary"
              ng-disabled="!form.$valid || vm.submitBusy">
            Sign in
            <span ng-if="vm.submitBusy"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
  <p>Forgot your password? Reset it
      <a ui-sref="auth.reset">here</a>.</p>
  <p>Trying to create a team?
      <a ui-sref="auth.join.personal">Sign up</a> to get started.</p>
</div>
```

form

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    token = forms.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.cached_user = None
        self.request = request
        kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

        if len(self._errors) > 0:
            return cleaned_data
        else:
            email = cleaned_data.get('email')
            password = cleaned_data.get('password')

            if email is None or password is None:
                messages.error(self.request, 'Please enter an email and password.')
                return forms.ValidationError("Error")
            else:
                self.cached_user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)

                if self.cached_user is None:
                    self._errors["password"] = self.error_class(["Password incorrect. Passwords are case sensitive."])
                elif not self.cached_user.is_active:
                    messages.error(self.request,
                                   'This account is inactive. Please check your inbox for our confirmation email, and '
                                   'click the link within to activate your account.')
                    raise forms.ValidationError("Error")

        if not cleaned_data.get('remember_me'):
            self.request.session.set_expiry(0)

        return cleaned_data

    def get_user(self):
        return self.cached_user
```

view

```
def login(request):
    # """ -Log in the user if credentials are valid """
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned_data = form.clean()

            account = Account.objects.get(email=cleaned_data['email'], password=cleaned_data['password'])

            if cleaned_data['token']:

                token = cleaned_data['token']
                invite = OrgInvite.objects.get(token=token)
                org = Org.objects.get(id=invite.org_id)
                if not invite:
                    raise Exception("Invitation token is invalid.")
                if invite.used == True:
                    raise Exception("Invitation token has already been used.")

                org_member = OrgMember.objects.get(account_id=account.id)
                if org_member:
                    raise Exception("Account is already in team.")
                else:
                    org.add_members(account.id, False, invite.is_admin)
                    invite.used = False

                    # add_to_welcome(org_id=org.id, account_id=account.id, inviter_id=invite.token)

            else:
                pass

        context = {
            'message': 'ok',
            'next': '/app/'
        }

        return composeJsonResponse(200, "", context)
```

[image]

Comment: `form.is_valid()` will call `form.clean()` so you shouldn't call it explicitly. To get form data after the clean, you do `cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data`.

Comment: What makes you think the form is unbound, or that that is the reason why validation is failing?

Comment: When I debug and set a breakpoint in my view, the forms bound property is coming up as false. I included it in an image. Its a tiny slither at the end so its a little hard to see.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a common mistake: you have changed the signature of the form class's initialization function so that the first parameter is the request. So when you do `LoginForm(request.POST)`, the POST data goes to the `request` argument, not the `data`.

You *could* fix this by ensuring that you do always pass the request - `LoginForm(request, request.POST)` - but a much better way is not to change the signature, and pass the request as a kwarg and get it from the `**kwargs` dict.

Comment: Ahh, I see, that makes perfect sense. I just changed the forms initialization function's parameters, and it is now coming up as bound, Thanks Daniel.

Comment: Would you please write more details? It is not clear how to fix the problem.